# Align multiple text label and input label in jQuery mobile

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I got a problem with jQuery mobile. I want to align the text label and input label in the same line.

I tried this CSS:

```
.input-topic {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 15px;
}

.input-content {
display: block;
float: left;
}

.input {
height: 20px;
}
```

And when I use

```
<label for="LitNameInput" class="input-topic">Name:</label>
<div class="input-content">
<input type="text" id="LitNameInput" placeholder="Name Surname" class="input"><p style="margin: 1px;"></p>
</div>
```

It works if the with of the screen size is suitable, otherwise it shown a horrible result!!

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leaderdevil/7K58w/), so you can change the width of the result section to see what's happen.

Thank you for all suggestions and solutions.

Comment: why using `float:left` and `display: inline-block;` same time?

Comment: I'm a beginner of web developer. Can you give me a suggestion which one you prefer? @KheemaPandey

Comment: this will help you.. http://css-tricks.com/tips-for-creating-great-web-forms/

Comment: It useful but I try removing `display: inline-block;` and it still not solve my problem. ;( @KheemaPandey

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery Mobile Field Containers: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/forms-field-contain/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You want Name, Telephone and Email to be on the same line? I would recommend using responsive grids and field contain provided by jQuery Mobile. That way on bigger widths they would all fit on the same line but on the smaller on they would stack.

Check out jQuery Mobile: **[Field Contain](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/forms-field-contain/)** and **[Grids](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/grids/)**(scroll down to the Responsive Grids section if you want the grids to stack which in this case I would recommend)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want something like Name []<br> Telephone []<br> Email []<br>, where [] means input label and <br> is newline. Is the Field Contains and Grids will drop the column into a row when screen's width is too small?

Comment: Yes the responsive grids will drop the field contains onto a row of their own if the screens width is small. Field contain does something similar where is drops the input or "[]" on a new line below the label if there isn't enough space

Comment: Is there any ways to force this auto-drop?

Comment: Something like this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6qa3/). Note I only changed markup for the name, telephone and email elements

Comment: I develop a mobile application and I worry that the screen is too small to show the label in the same line as input label. You can see the application width from application screenshot in my previous question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557894/collapsible-set-expand-multiple-listview-at-a-timel)

Comment: Make the result window smaller, the input drops to the next line. So on a mobile screen it will drop the input on the next row

Comment: Yes, but I prefer it to be in the same row.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I didn't understand something then.. If you're worried about screen being too small then why wouldn't you want the input to drop on the next line? In any case use non-responsive grids then... Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAuPp/)

Comment: Oh, that's what I want!! But I question that can I set the width of the text label of the grid to wrap my content?

Comment: Yes you can apply styles to `<div class="ui-block-a">` or `<div class="ui-block-b">` Initially both those divs have 50% width you can change that if you apply a style on the div like this: `<div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 30%;>`